# Do Intel integrated graphics support nearest neighbor scaling?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, integrated-graphics, scaling

On a MacBook Pro with Retina Display, I'd like to run Windows with exactly half the screen resolution in order to maintain 100% scaling (2880x1800 -> 1440x900). However, I've heard that if you set a custom resolution to half the native one, the resulting image will be blurry, since to [forced bilinear interpolation.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59283/why-is-a-retina-macbook-running-1440x900-grainy-under-boot-camp)

At least 
that's for the Nvidia graphics. But what about Intel integrated graphics? Can they support nearest neighbor scaling so rendering half the native screen resolution won't look blurry, or do they too force bilinear interpolation?

Comment: You may find several solution to try in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4600468).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, they indeed do, at least with the drivers included with the latest bootcamp support package.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If they do support nearest neighbor scaling, where can I find the setting for that?