# Can I use nearest-neighbor scaling with Intel Iris and Windows 10 on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, resolution, macbook-pro-retina

If I were to dual-boot Windows 10 on a 15" Retina MacBook Pro, would I be able to change the screen resolution and use nearest-neighbor scaling?

The 15" rMBP has a 2880x1800 screen and I'd like for the resolution to be 1440x900 (perfect 4-to-1 pixel scaling) and not blurry at all. The blur is caused by [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Scaling_methods), so using nearest-neighbor scaling instead would eliminate it. I've read that [this isn't possible with nVidia but might be with Intel](https://superuser.com/questions/759070/do-intel-integrated-graphics-support-nearest-neighbor-scaling).

Is this possible through something like an Intel control panel?

Comment: Did you ever find a work around? Looking for the same thing here.

Comment: @Mahn I did not, sorry. I ended up asking Intel support about it and they said it was not possible. Ended up eventually getting a Lenovo laptop.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for replying. I guess I'll have to use another machine as well.

Comment: Wasn;t 2880x1800 with DPI scaling to 200% an option?